# Equivalent of combine_first in pandas available in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to update a `DataFrame` with another when certain conditions are met.

The `combine_first` function in `pandas` `DataFrame` works well. Is there an equivalent method available in Spark to update `DataFrame`s efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strict equivalent, but if you have a common key, you can join and coalesce:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col, isnan, when

keys = ["index"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4]])

sdf1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1.reset_index()).alias("df1")
sdf2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2.reset_index()).alias("df2")


def first_of(c1, c2):
    return coalesce(when(~isnan(c1), c1), when(~isnan(c2), c2))


sdf1.join(sdf2, keys, "fullouter").select(keys + [
    first_of(sdf1[c], sdf2[c]).alias(c) for c in sdf1.columns if c not in keys
]).show()

# +-----+---+---+
# |index|  0|  1|
# +-----+---+---+
# |    0|  1|4.0|
# +-----+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. Except for the case that when there are extra columns in either of the dataframes, that needs to be in the final updated one as well. Can the join be modified accordingly to achieve that?

Comment: Also would like to mention that the column names are dynamic.